# Reading from terminal without waiting for "newline" with Java

Tags: java, terminal, user-input

I'm trying to read every character that user inputs without waiting for a "newline".

This code doesn't work, as AFAIK Scanner waits for the newline character before sending input to the application

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
if(s.hasNext()){
    char c = s.next().charAt(0);
}
```

I also tried with BufferedReader:

```
System.out.println("Input something: ");
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(!b.ready()){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
System.out.println("Now it's ready, i'm reading the first char");
char c = (char)b.read();
```

But the output is:

```
Input something:
> abcde
Now it's ready, i'm reading the first char
```

So it is always waiting for the newline character.

Is there any way to read user input without waiting for newline with Java?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: why don't you just use `System.in.read()` ?

Comment: Because it waits for the newline character.

Comment: What about using a `BufferedInputStream` and checking if characters are `available()` ?

Comment: @drone.ah It also waits for newline character.

Comment: You need to put the console in raw mode, which isn't cross-platform. Maybe try jreadline or whatever the interface to deadline is.